# Read string of json values from config file c#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have json object which is reading like configuration.Getsection("XYZconfig").Get(); in code it is working fine in local.
After inserting the config values in azure keyvault the XYZconfig section is taking as below, The quotation is appending before and after brackets. so it is unable to read using configuration.Getsection("XYZconfig").Get(). How to read this config values.

"XYZconfig": "{ "key1":"vaule1",
"key2":"value2",
"key3":"value3"
}"

Comment: you can use `Trim` like `var configSection = configuration.GetSection("XYZconfig").Value.Trim('"');`

Comment: Hi @Jajula Siva, have you tried using `Newtonsoft.Json` to handle escaped strings 
which like mjb said: `var XYZconfig = _configuration.GetSection("XYZconfig").Value; var key1 = JObject.Parse(XYZconfig).GetValue("key1");`?

Answer (score 0):

escape the string sequence

```
"XYZconfig": "{ \"key1\":\"vaule1\", \"key2\":\"value2\", \"key3\":\"value3\" }"
```

List of other string sequence:

https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Comment: still it is not working. after formatting the json like above

Answer (score 0):

To access the configuration values you stored in Azure KeyVault from your ASP.NET Core web app, you can refer to following code snippet:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {

        var root = config.Build();
        config.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{your_keyvault_name_here}.vault.azure.net/", $"{clientid_here}", $"{client_secret_here}");
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

*Read configuration value:*

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration config)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _config = config;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var val = _config["XYZconfig"];
```

[image]